# Best way to use UITabBarController and UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

for these two elements in iOS programming we can create them graphically with the "Interface Builder" (integrated in XCode) or programmatically.

Which are the pros and cons of two methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally prefer using IB, starting with the tab bar template, then replacing the respective controllers in IB with navigation controllers.

I would recommend this [tutorial](http://www.forwardecho.com/2008/11/creating-navigation-control-inside-tab.html)